# R data.table grepl column on another column in i

Tags: r, data.table

Can I subset for when a string in column A is in column B?

Example:

```
x <- data.table(a=letters, y=paste0(letters,"x"))

x[grepl(a, y)]
x[like(y, a)]
```

Both return only a one row data.table of the first row and the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I would expect this to return all rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code applies `grepl` to each row with the `a` and `y` as a pair of that row. Basically, the first argument of grepl cannot be a vector with length larger than 1, so looping or lapply based approach is needed.

```
x[mapply(grepl, a, y), ]
#     a  y
#  1: a ax
#  2: b bx
#  3: c cx
#  4: d dx
#  5: e ex
#  6: f fx
#  7: g gx
#  8: h hx
#  9: i ix
# 10: j jx
# 11: k kx
# 12: l lx
# 13: m mx
# 14: n nx
# 15: o ox
# 16: p px
# 17: q qx
# 18: r rx
# 19: s sx
# 20: t tx
# 21: u ux
# 22: v vx
# 23: w wx
# 24: x xx
# 25: y yx
# 26: z zx
#     a  y
```

Comment: Or `x[Vectorize(like)(y, a)]` or `x[Vectorize(grepl)(a, y)]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks for sharing the information about `Vectorize`. This is my first time to see this. I think this is a very useful function.

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility could be using `dplyr`. Something like:

```
x <- data.table(a=letters, y=paste0(letters,"x"))

x %>% rowwise() %>%
  filter(grepl(a,y)) %>% as.data.frame()

    a  y
 1: a ax
 2: b bx
 3: c cx
 4: d dx
 5: e ex
 6: f fx
 7: g gx
 8: h hx
 9: i ix
........ so
```